# How to display images from local server in tomcat in android image view

Tags: java, android

I am trying set image in android image view. 
I used below code to set image in image view :

```
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("http://172.22.30.55:8080/data/product_images/"+data.get("col_1"));
imageView =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

But I am getting below exception :

```
 E/BitmapFactory(3663): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/172.22.30.55:8080/data/product_images/056075419be6ed982cb63eba81056396.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What I am trying to do get the image file from the local server but working my code.

What is my mistake?

Comment: `172.0.0.0` is an address of a network, it is most probably not the actual ip address of your server.

Comment: I know. But in my code I am using the correct IP. Used this as sample IP

Comment: Lesson of the day: If you provide non-working code you lead people who want to help you on the wrong path and they solve problems that have nothing to do with your actual problem. Always post an [mcve].

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Without looking at the documentation my guess would be: The `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` function can't handle http urls, it looks for the file on the local filesystem and can't find it.

Comment: is your url working in your browser? it would be easier if you use picasso or glide.

Comment: @KaranMer Yes. Its working in browser

Comment: have you provided internet permission in your manifest?

Comment: @KaranMer. Yes. I have added

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     ImageView imageview= (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.product_image);

        try{
            String url = "http://172.22.30.55:8080/data/product_images/"+data.get("col_1");
            URL ulrn = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            if (null != bmp)
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            else
                System.out.println("Bitmap is NULL");

                 if (con != null) {   
                      con.disconnect();  
                  } 
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
```

Comment: While this would most probably solve the problem I can already see the next exception arising.

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso to load image from network. you only need to do is write below lines.

```
String url = "http://172.22.30.55:8080/data/product_images/"+data.get("col_1");
imageView =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
Picasso.with (YourActivity.this)
                    .load(Uri.parse(url))
                    .into(imageView);
```

You also need to provide **INTERNET** permission in your manifest and **add dependencies for Picasso in your build.gradle**.

Comment: are you using android studio or eclipse?

Comment: in this case you need to add jar file for Picasso to your project.

Comment: you can download it from here  repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.5.2/picasso-2.5.2.jar

Comment: copy paste this jar file inside your projects libs/ folder